# Running python in php for image processing

Tags: php, python, database, opencv, image-processing

hi everyone
I want to run a python script through php in which i've to do image processing and update a database and then use that database in same php program.
Is it feasible ? 
If yes then how ?
I am a beginner so apology if the question isn't up to the mark.
Please help me making my first project :)

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, please be a bit more specific when asking question: *What have you tried so far with code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 0):

you can use `exec` command to run python script from php

```
exec(python script_name parameter)
```

To know more about `exec` go to this link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

I've used php to call python machine learning script.Try this

Example for Ubuntu

```
$values=shell_exec('/usr/bin/python two.py '.$ing.'');
```

Example for Windows

```
$values=shell_exec('C:\Python27\python two.py '.$ing.'');
```

$ing is the variable passed to the script. Remember to give the absolute path of python. It was pretty feasible for me. But performance mostly depends on your python script as the php just executes the python code